# Vue 2.0: Parents not responding to child event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a sidebar child component with buttons that change the tab:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="employee-sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar full-height col-" data-color="purple">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="dash-board">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li v-bind:class="{ active: activeLink == 'dashboard' }">
                    <a href="#dashboard" @click="changeTab('dashboard')">
                        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li v-bind:class="{ active: activeLink == 'team' }">
                    <a href="#radio" @click="changeTab('team')">
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                        <p>Team</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary clear-filter">Clear</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

When I call `@click="changeTab('dashboard')"` it calls a function in the child component and emits a `changeTab` event:

```
Vue.component('employee-sidebar', {
  template: '#employee-sidebar',
  props: {},
  data: function() {
    return {
      activeLink: 'dashboard'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeTab: function(tab) {
      // Always see this console log
      console.log(tab)
      this.activeLink = tab
      this.$emit('changeTab', tab)
    }
  }
})
```

When I call the component in the parent I listen for this event:

```
<employee-sidebar v-on:changeTab="changeTheTab(activeLink)"></employee-sidebar>
```

But the `changeTheTab()` function is never called in the parent:

```
changeTheTab: function(tab) {
  // Never see this console log
  console.log(tab)
  this.activeLink = tab
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Try `v-on:changeTab="changeTheTab"`, you don't need to pass in a parameter

Comment: Make you event name all lowercase - it will fix your bug. HTML is not case sensitive.

Comment: This is working, but I can't seem to pass the tab argument which I need in the parent

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wostex for the lowercase tip, I was able to update my component to the following:

```
Vue.component('employee-sidebar', {
  template: '#employee-sidebar',
  props: {},
  data: function() {
    return {
      activeLink: 'dashboard'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeTab: function(tab) {
      console.log(tab)
      this.activeLink = tab
      this.$emit('change_tab', tab)
    }
  }
})
```

and in the parent:

```
<employee-sidebar v-on:change_tab="(tab) => activeLink = tab"></employee-sidebar>
```